# Проверка занимаемой памяти запущенного процесса через BAT

Tags: cmd, bat

Подскажите пожалуйста батник который проверяет каждые секунды запущен ли процесс и если например он запущен и занимает больше 150мб памяти в оперативной памяти то дальше выполняются следующие сценарии

Answer (score 1):

Вводим в консоли `tasklist/?` и внимательно изучаем ключи `/M` (имя модуля exe) + `/FI` (фильтр вывода). Там есть даже примеры, которые остаётся завернуть в батник.